# Update httpd-apach 2.4.37 to 2.4.38 error on centos 8

Tags: apache, http, httpd.conf

The latest version of Apache httpd for Centos 8 I can find is 2.4.37 from the Centos 8 AppStream Repository, unless I download the source code direct from Apache and compile. I understand self compiled versions is not recommended.

This version is showing a number of vulnerabilities when being scanned by our vulnerability scanner.

Anyone any ideas of when a later version is due to come out for Centos 8, or if there are any other repositories out there with a later version for Centos 8?

I have try to manual download httpd version to installed on my machine, but still cannot.